# Does fabric-ca-server support the generation of key pairs on behalf of the client?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From the Fabric CA documentation it is clear that key generation occurs on the client (i.e., fabric-ca-client) side and that the generated public key is sent (together with the CSR) to the CA (i.e., fabric-ca-server) for certification.

What about the other common PKI use case wherein the client just sends a CSR and has the CA generate both public and private keys returning the certificate of the public key and the private key back to the client?

Does Fabric CA support this use case? If so, where might I find documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Fabric CA supports this use case which would explain why it's not in the documentation. However Fabric is not reliant on Fabric CA to create it's certificates. You can use your own process to generate your keys and certificates so long as the keys are of the type supported by Fabric which is ECDSA.

Comment: Using something other than Fabric CA is a good point - thanks for that tip! The documentation indicates that other key algorithms are also supported as I would expect if it is to align with NIST 800-57. See https://henry-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/ca-setup.html for further details.

Comment: hyperledger fabric only supports ECDSA and IdeMix (and only in a limited way, ie only the java non-gateway sdk can work with idemix I believe and only Go chaincode can do extra stuff with txns submitted with idemix) credentials. Fabric-ca supports idemix as well but that's the full extent available. Hyperledger Fabric does not support RSA

Answer (score 0):

So after a little more research I've come to the following conclusion (pls note david_k's comment that you are not compelled to use Fabric CA Server at all):

It would appear that there is a clear preference for client generated keys based on a reading of section 3.4.1 of the current documentation (as per 24.03.2022).

This leaves the question of key management policy which seems to be following NIST 800-57 here taken from the documentation on https://henry-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/ca-setup.html i.e,

> Elliptic Curve (ECDSA) offers the following key size options:
> size  ASN1 OID    Signature Algorithm
> 256   prime256v1  ecdsa-with-SHA256
> 384   secp384r1   ecdsa-with-SHA384
> 521   secp521r1   ecdsa-with-SHA512
>
> RSA offers the following key size options:
> size  Modulus (bits)  Signature Algorithm
> 2048  2048    sha256WithRSAEncryption
> 4096  4096    sha512WithRSAEncryption

I am guessing that the fabric-ca-server is enforcing this policy.

Comment: I believe the code for RSA is still in fabric-ca but hyperledger fabric doesn't support RSA (it may have done in the past and the code has since been removed)